# Is it possible to detect a user's browser(like IE11) and then redirect them to another(like Chrome)?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11

I have an application that does not work in IE. I am assigned the task of redirecting the user to Chrome if they open the application in any other browser. Is this possible? If not, how can I detect what browser a user is utilizing so that I may display a banner that instructs them to use Chrome?

I have researched this topic but have not found any documentation on this besides the jQuery Browser Rejection plugin

The Dream goal would be to launch chrome if the user has it installed or suggest a download if the user does not have it installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221722/browser-detection)

Comment: So that link is assuming you want to do the detection on the server side. Duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser) if you're doing client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: A website that launchs another browser on a users computer would be evil. I know of no browser that allows such evilness.