# Target different Javascript versions with TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-3

TypeScript can globally target different versions of Javascript - you can switch between transpiling ES3, ES5 or ES6.

We have to support IE, so ES3 is our lowest common denominator.

However, good browsers (like Chrome) already support ES6, and will be able to run the significantly smaller ES6 code with optimisations.

So, from the same TypeScript source I want to serve ES3 to IE and ES6 to Chrome.

- Is there a way to make TypeScript transpile multiple JS files (maybe as `*.es3` and `*.es6` or something like that) so we can pick which version to serve? (Ideally in VS 2015)
- Alternatively in C# can I access the TypeScript transpiler to complete the step at run time?

Comment: Are you using a JS build tool like Gulp, Webpack, or even Grunt? If so, you can simply factor your TS build into a function and run it twice with different targets.

Comment: @ssube - unfortunately not, this is a C# VS 2015 project file upgraded from older versions. VS appears to use hard coded settings in the .csproj file rather than tsconfig.json files like VS Code does.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually specify [which version you want to transpile](http://david-barreto.com/introduction-to-the-typescript-transpiler/) to using the command line (`--target ES3`).

You can also specify an output directory, so that you can output both ES6 and ES3 transpiled code, and then chose which to reference on the fly (using [old style IE ifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605894/replace-script-if-viewed-in-ie9)).

Answer (score 3):

How about using different `tsconfig.json` files?

For example, something like:

```
 - root  
    - ts-source  
    - js-es3  
       - tsconfig.json  
       - js  
    - js-es5  
       - tsconfig.json  
       - js
```

Then the `root/js-es3/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES3",
        "outDir": "js",
        "rootDir": "../ts-srouce"
    }
}
```

And the `root/js-es5/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "outDir": "js",
        "rootDir": "../ts-srouce"
    }
}
```

I'm not a visual studio user so I don't know how to support different `tsconfig.json` files there, but even if you can't, then you can compile it using `tsc`.

Comment: I think this would be the answer in most IDE's/editors, but unfortunately VS2015 doesn't support multiple tsconfig files, completely ignores `rootDir` and has a bug where `outDir` gets a copy of the output but an in-place copy is created too.

Comment: @Keith Are you sure? I'm not a VS kinda guy, but according to [this ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4714) it seems to be supported.

Comment: Yup, it's taken me so long to reply because I was testing it extensively. I think it is a [bug in VS2015](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3101865) rather than a fault in TypeScript. The free VS Code handles multiple tsconfig files fine, but full fat VS2015 with a .csproj fails hard at the moment. Maybe they'll fix it in Update 4.

Comment: You can always run the compiler from the command line... And you can use a different IDE for the typescript part (WebStorm is amazing, but you also have the VSCode thing, and even atom can work well)